# android Map works only in launch activity

Tags: android, dictionary

I tried a lot but still have no explanation/solution, why map isn't loading

I am using

Android Studio ,Google Map V 2, Google play services 7.5.0 and done other things like creating api key with SHA1 etc

I have one activity called TestMapAct.class which contains the necessary code for showing map in the application.

Map works if I make TestMapAct as my launcher activity
Map works when I call it just after my splash activity.
Map doesn't work if I call like this splash activity -> Login activity -> TestMapAct

Here is my TestMapAct class

```
    package com.propstack.propstack.activities;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.propstack.propstack.R;

/**
 * Created by propstack on 06-11-2015.
 */
public class TestMapAct extends FragmentActivity {

    private static GoogleMap mMap;
    private static Double latitude, longitude;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_location_info);

        latitude = 26.78;
        longitude = 72.56;

        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    public void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.

            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.location_map)).getMap();


//            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) ProfileActivity.fragmentManager
//                    .findFragmentById(R.id.location_map)).getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null)
                setUpMap();
        }
    }

    private static void setUpMap() {
        // For showing a move to my loction button
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        // For dropping a marker at a point on the Map
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("My Home").snippet("Home Address"));
        // For zooming automatically to the Dropped PIN Location
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitude,
                longitude), 12.0f));
    }
}
```

Corresponding XML Code :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/location_map"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Manifest details

```
    <permission
        android:name="com.propstack.propstack.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.propstack.propstack.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <!-- Required OpenGL ES 2.0. for Maps V2 -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="Key goes here" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Log cat when map doesn't appears:

```
ResourcesManager﹕ Asset path '/system/framework/com.android.media.remotedisplay.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.

ResourcesManager﹕ Asset path '/system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.

ContextImpl﹕ Failed to ensure directory: /storage/sdcard1/Android/data/com.propstack.propstack/cache
```

Please help me out here

Comment: can u please show me the activities in manifest.? did u declared it in manifest.xml

Comment: Yes, of course I have declared that activity in manifest

Comment: I suggest 3 things: Update Play Services to latest 8.3.0, use latest support Activity class `AppCompatActivity` and use `implements OnMapReadyCallback` to get callback when map is ready to use.

Answer (score 0):

If you have SSL Pinning enabled on your app, add the server certificate from this domain **clients4.google.com** to your *SSLSocketFactory* keystore then verify the hostname using *HostnameVerifier*. That's how I solved mine with the similar behaviour.